# Rails Logic ! Pre Order ads, how to store the information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, logic

In an app, a client can pre command many ads.

What's the better way to store this information :

**#1**
Create empty ad with "pre-order" state

**#2**
Use a pre_order_ads column in the database to store the number of pre-order ads

Is anybody can give me some logic ?

Thanks !

Comment: What about two models? `PreOrder` which can lead to the creation of an `Order` if the purchase is confirmed.

Comment: This should be the logic : A user buy multiple ads. So One Order has Many ads. One User Has Many Ads, So when my order is paid, I should create many ads with "ordered" or "pre order" state ! No ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for this configuration:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ads

  validates :state, presence: true, inclusion: { in: Order::STATES }
  STATES = ['preordered', 'ordered', 'confirmed', 'shipped', #...]
```

This means that the `Order` holds the logic about ordered/pre-ordered. You might want to be able to pre-order some of the Ads of an Order and not the whole Order. If so, use a state attribute on the Ad model.

Comment: I think is the better way ! Thanks !